# Are Colossus' Eyes Vulnerable?

Tags: marvel, x-men, super-hero, colossus

The mutant [Colossus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_%28comics%29) in X-men is a tank: he's big, strong, and tough.  He can take it and dish it out.  He's big, and gets bigger when he activates his mutant ability: he grows at least a foot in height, gains superhuman strength, and his body transforms into a form of 'organic steel'.

In his armored form, he's bulletproof, highly resistant to all physical damage (including heat and cold, explosions, etc), and able to go without food, water, or oxygen for extended periods - maybe indefinitely.

Are his eyes a weak point?  I know he can still see, and thus be blinded, but are his eyes more vulnerable to physical damage than the rest of him?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per the Marvel.com specs on him, "Even his eyes become steel-like."

http://marvel.com/universe/Colossus
(You have to expand the 'Powers' section to see the part I quoted.)

Comment: I seem to recall him being attacked in the eyes at some point, though...or am I mistaken?

Comment: @Jeff - Might you be thinking of Ben Grimm/The Thing? His eyes *were* vulnerable.

Comment: While his eyes might become harder and more resilient it is likely that they would be much more vulnerable than other parts of him since the actual cellular matter being converted to steel would still be less powerful than other cells in his body and have significantly less density overall. He could likely repel small arms fire, but larger more powerful weapons could conceivably penetrate his ocular cavity successfully. So he might still protect his eyes from a physical threat.